# Ignored files in Git would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git, merge, gitignore, ignore, pull

When I do pull in my server, this is the message I get:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by merge:
>           css/custom.css
>           images/logo.png Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

But those 2 files are ignored in my .gitignore like this:

```
# general
inc/config.php
css/custom.css
favicon.ico
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: in the beginning, you committed these file into repo after which git is  tracking those files after that you must have added them to git ignore file if this is your scenario git rm --cached <yourfilename> will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Some team member has already committed those file so when you make a git pull you will recover those committed files changes and in your next commit those files will be considered as ignored file.

2) Before merging you need to:

- **commit your modifications:** `git add path/to/modified-file` then `git commit -m "commit message"` and finally `git pull`

***Or***

- **Stash your modifications:** `git stash` then `git pull` 
  And to recover your modifications again use `git stash pop`

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!